# Embed Webbrowser remove/delete certain elements

Tags: vb.net, element

Is it possible, or is there a Webbrowser that allows me to visit a website and delete certain elements from the webpage so they won't be visible for the user anymore?

Basically Im creating a gameoverlay with a farm route map which shows certain spots with enemies etc.

That website has some ads on it and I don't want them to be displayed on the embedded browser.
So is it possible to remove those ads by id / element somehow or is it possible to add a adblock extension to it?

Currently I'm using cefsharp winforms webbrowser and I do know how to load websites but thats about it. In case It doesn't work with that browser I am willing to move to another one since my preference is to remove those annoying ads first.

Thanks for anyone helping.

Comment: You could fetch the page source first, save it to a tmp file, edit as needed, then load the tmp file into a browser control.

Comment: If you are using an embedded web browser (not web control) then you can load or embed some ad-blocker in case you are using chromium source or firefox build from source. In case using default web control of .net framwork then you need to manually edit the webpage after downloading as mentioned by @J. Scott Elblein.